# Looking for a large capacitive touch array controller

Tags: capacitive, touchscreen, sensing, touch-panel, touch

I'm building a capacitive touch panel.

It has an odd shape, so I resulted to building my own with the [capacitive diamond array](https://cdn.comsol.com/wordpress/2014/12/Capacitive-touchscreen-sensor-geometry.png) solution.

It doesn't have a screen underneath, so it's all contained on a PCB.

My issue is that I would need a quite large number of rows/cols (20-30), and I'm having trouble finding a sensing chip that could handle this amount of sensors.
The [PE5004](https://www.pe-gmbh.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/FS_PE5004.pdf) would have been a perfect candidate as it could be daisy chained for more sensors, however the manufacturer says they discontinued this product.

Are there any similar products out on the market, or is there a different way to establish a large touch sensing array?

Comment: Could the Texas Instruments MSP430 MCUs which support CapTIvate help? Given they are programmable MCUs perhaps multiple MCUs could be used, each handling part of the panel, and use communication between the MCUs. [True Matrix Capability](https://software-dl.ti.com/msp430/msp430_public_sw/mcu/msp430/CapTIvate_Design_Center/1_83_00_08/exports/docs/users_guide/html/CapTIvate_Technology_Guide_html/markdown/ch_basics.html?highlight=matrix#true-matrix-capability) has some information about creating an input matrix, but haven't checked the largest matrix of inputs you can get from a single MCU.

Comment: Excellent recommendation, capTIvate supports mutual measurement mode. The largest achievable matrix seems to be 8x8, so I would need a 3x3 array of them.

Comment: This person is building a wacom-style tablet themselves; maybe their approach might inform you a bit. https://mastodon.social/@TT_392@fosstodon.org/111235415992748227

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the ideas,
After a bit more digging I landed on trying my luck with the [mXT640UD-CCU001](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/ATmXT640U).
Which is a maXTouch 640-node Touchscreen Controller from Microchip.
It's a bit out of my comfort zone, but the application notes seem to be detailed enough to get started.